# Find the last child of a specific ul tag from multiple ul in a page

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML in the page

```
<ul> 
<li>list</li>
<li>list</li>
</ul>

<ul> 
<li>list</li>
<li>find this with jQuery</li>
</ul>

<ul> 
<li>list</li>
<li>list</li>
</ul>
```

I tried the following script but doesn't find the one which i want

```
$('ul li').last();
```

I'm trying to get the list item 'find this with jQuery'

Comment: So how do you target specific UL, using index or handler or what??? Why this one and not another one? Your question is quite ambiguous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 'eq' selector to find element by index.something like this:

```
 $('ul').eq('1').find('li').last();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/77KRN/)**

Comment: In OP example, this is not the last UL

Comment: Dont use find as it will search through the entire tree from the ul(assuming that it contains nested ul's).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
console.log($('ul').eq(1).children().eq(1).text())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty simple . Just get the `index` of your `ul`, then get the last `li` of that `ul` and then get the `text` for that `li`.

**JS :**

```
var li = $('ul').eq(1).find(' li').last();
console.log(li.text());
```

**[WORKING FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bYUX7/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

for last Ul li

```
$( "ul" ).last().find("li").last().text();
```

for a specific ul id:

> $( "#ulid" ).last().find("li").text();

Answer (score 0):

> Find the last child of a specific ul tag from multiple ul in a page

You have to get the desired `ul` first, before you get the last li in it. You can use the eq to get the specific ul.

```
$('ul').eq(index).find('li').last();
```

Comment: Dont use `find` as it will search through the entire tree from the ul(assuming that it contains nested ul's). `children` is what you should use to search to a single level down the DOM tree.